# how to count all the rows of a table starting from specific row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql

how to count all the rows of a table starting from specific row by `id`?

like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aptec ORDER BY id ASC AFTER id = 1000;
```

is that possible ?

Comment: the order by statement with the ASC should always be last of a mysql query.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aptec WHERE id > 1000
```